# Profiling on Restcomm USSD Gateway

Tags: profiling, benchmarking, gateway, ussd, restcomm

does exist a tool to stress Restcomm USSD Gateway, for profiling purposes?
I've already made a testing tool, but it can't increase CPU usage more than 30%.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/RestComm/jss7/tree/master/map/load as a load test tool and potentially contribute to it to improve it as well !